# Firebase commandline to list functions from GCP firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have 100ds of functions deployed to firebase and I would like to know if I can list the remote functions on my machine using the firebase command line tools.

I want to see the list of functions deployed.

What I am trying to solve is:

- Batch deploy functions to avoid deployment limit.
- Deployment error when function deleted/renamed locally and then deploying whole functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but FYI you can list the deployed functions from the Google Cloud console (not the Firebase one), here: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=<project_name>

Comment: That sounds like an answer Renaud. ;-) Especially when you add that the Firebase CLI does not have an ability to list functions.

Comment: Thanks Renaud, I know I can see the list of functions on web console, I am looking for something using the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the exact answer from Google support.

Currently, Firebase CLI doesn’t have any command to list deployed functions, whereas “gcloud functions list” CLI from Cloud SDK shows the list instead.

[More details found here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/list)

Answer (score 6):

While it doesn't seem to be documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#command_reference), you can list all deployed Cloud Functions when you have `firebase-tools` installed with `firebase functions:list`. The command is also mentioned in `firebase --help`.

Verified with `firebase-tools` version 10.5.0

Comment: If you have multiple projects, you may need to add a `--project <projectname>` to the command.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this answer, there is no CLI command that allows listing all the deployed functions for your project. The available commands can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#commands

However, note that you can list the deployed functions in the Google Cloud console (not the Firebase one) by opening: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=your_project_name

Answer (score 2):

Cli command prints the list in table format that is hard to parse. I use node script for this

```
import * as client from 'firebase-tools';

(async () => {
  const functions = await client.functions.list();
  const functionNames: string[] = functions.map(({ id }) => id);

  console.log('functionNames', functionNames);
})();
```